# How to change terminal prefix to $

Tags: xterm

My Xterm always print:

```
  tony@tony-ThinkPad-Edge-E540:~$
```

I want it to print only

```
 ~$
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Xterm also read `.bashrc` when starting. Add this line to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
PS1=~$\
```

And restart xterm.